# friend function of a class

Tags: c++, oop, function, friend

Can I make a function that is not member of any class be a friend of a class?If so could someone point me out to the syntax? I used [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html)  page as reference .On that it only has a function that is part of another class being made a friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. The syntax for this should be obvious from the example you pointed out:

```
friend return_type free_function(args);
```

Comment: args?In the example that they give at the bottom of the page they only use find() and not find (int) .I am confused

Comment: @Manish: `args` is whatever the declaration of the function arguments is. I'm referring to the example that's a bit before the one you just mentioned.

Comment: Right..but which one is correct? They are contrary to each other but looks like what you mentioned above is correct?

Comment: @Manish: I don't understand you. There are no incorrect answers. You just prepend `friend` to the **declaration** of a function -be it member or free-, and you get a **friend declaration**.

Comment: Ok so what I am saying is if you look at how find is defined it takes an int argument.But when they declare it a friend function they dont include that .They say friend int BinaryTree::find()  instead of what should have been friend int BinaryTree::find(int) if we go by your logic to include args .Probably a small error and I think it should be the second option in accordance with what you said .But it was confusing when I first saw